# Computing numerical derivative with gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, numerical-methods, derivative

I've been trying to compute numerically the derivative using gnuplot, using the scripts in this other [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751226/how-can-i-plot-the-derivative-of-a-graph-in-gnuplot), even with the same data file. However I keep getting this error:

```
gnuplot> d(y) = ($0 == 0) ? (y1 = y, 1/0) : (y2 = y1, y1 = y, y1-y2)
                                ^
         "prova.g", line 7: ')' expected
```

I don't know what to do here. Any help?

Comment: Which version of gnuplot are you running? I can only reproduce this error message with gnuplot 4.0 which is about 17 years old.

Comment: At startup it says: Version 4.2 patchlevel 6

Comment: This might be the reason. Can't you update to a newer version? Current version is 5.4

Comment: This is on a remote server owned by my uni, unfortunately, I don't think I can do it without authorization (which I wouldn't know where to get).

Comment: Hmmm, gnuplot 4.2.6 is from 2009. So, your administrators are 12 years behind?! Let me check if there might be a way which such an old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for numerical derivatives from my collection. Requires gnuplot >=5.0 and with the use of files instead of datablocks (and probably with some tweaking with gnuplot>=4.4.0).

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.0.0, Jan. 2015)

```
### numerical derivatives
reset session

# create some data
MyFunction = "sin(x)/x"
set table $Data
    set samples 150
    plot [-10:10] '+' u 1:(@MyFunction) w table
unset table

DerivX(colX) = (x0=x1,x1=column(colX),(x0+x1)/2.)
DerivY(colY) = (y0=y1,y1=column(colY),(y1-y0)/(x1-x0))

set table $Deriv1
    plot x1=y1=NaN $Data u (DerivX(1)):(DerivY(2)) w table
unset table

set table $Deriv2
    plot x1=y1=NaN $Deriv1 u (DerivX(1)):(DerivY(2)) w table
unset table

set table $Deriv3
    plot x1=y1=NaN $Deriv2 u (DerivX(1)):(DerivY(2)) w table
unset table

plot $Data   u 1:2 w l lc rgb "red"       ti MyFunction, \
     $Deriv1 u 1:2 w l lc rgb "web-green" ti "1st Derivative", \
     $Deriv2 u 1:2 w l lc rgb "blue"      ti "2nd Derivative", \
     $Deriv3 u 1:2 w l lc rgb "magenta"   ti "3rd Derivative"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** (version for gnuplot 4.2.6, Sept. 2009)

gnuplot 4.2.6 doesn't have datablocks and serial evaluation, but here is a cumbersome workaround without these features.

1. for illustration, the script creates a data file `SO68198576.dat` (you already have your input file)
2. plot the data file into another file `TEMP1` skipping the first data line
3. merge the files line by line into another file `TEMP2` using the system command `paste` (either on Linux already on the system or on Windows you have to install, e.g. `CoreUtils` from [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)).
4. now you can calculate `dx` and `dy` between two successive datapoints from column 1 and 4 and column 2 and 5, respectively.
5. since the files have different length, the last line(s) should be skipped. This can be done by the system command `head -n -2`.

That's how `TEMP2` looks like:

```
#Curve 0 of 1, 150 points   #Curve 0 of 1, 150 points
#x y type   #x y type
-10 -0.0544021  i   -9.86577 -0.0432646  i
-9.86577 -0.0432646  i  -9.73154 -0.0310307  i
-9.73154 -0.0310307  i  -9.59732 -0.0178886  i
...
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot 4.2.6, requires system commands `paste` and `head`)

```
### numerical derivative for gnuplot 4.2.6
reset

FILE = "SO68198576.dat"
set table FILE
    set samples 150
    plot sin(x)/x
unset table

TEMP1 = FILE.'1'
TEMP2 = FILE.'2'
set table TEMP1
    plot FILE u 1:2 every ::1
unset table

system(sprintf('paste %s %s > %s', FILE, TEMP1, TEMP2))
system(sprintf('head -n -2 %s > %s',TEMP2, TEMP1))

x0(col) = (column(col)+column(col+3))/2.
dx(col) = (column(col+3)-column(col))/2.
dy(col) = (column(col+3)-column(col))/2.

plot FILE u 1:2 w lp pt 7 title "Data", \
     TEMP1 u (x0(1)):(dy(2)/dx(1)) w lp pt 7 title "1st Derivative"
### end of script
```

**Result:** (screenshot gnuplot 4.2.6)

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, just had to change the data. Quite ingenious!

Comment: @AnotherUser glad to hear :-). Why did you have to change the data? Well, in your question you didn't show data. In any case, maybe you ask your administrators to update gnuplot to a more recent version, a 12 year old version is a bit too old.

Comment: Yes my question was regarding actual data, not just an analytic function. I will definitely bring up the update the next time I speak with my professor

Comment: @AnotherUser sorry, of course you have to change the data. You don't want `sin(x)/x` but _your_ datafile. You can also easily change the columns as needed.

Comment: Yes, I figured as much, was easy enough. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @AnotherUser actually, you can get rid of this strange last point in the graph if you remove the last two lines of `temp2.dat` via `system(sprintf('head -n -2 %s > %s',TEMP2, TEMP1))` and then plot `TEMP1` instead of `TEMP2`. Maybe there are better ways.